# In the UK, how do I convert from an address to a lat/long?

Tags: data, geocoding, ordnance-survey, united-kingdom

Please include where I can buy the dataset and how much it costs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future you should be able to use the LLPG (local Land and Property Gazetteer), which would return a British National Grid coordinate. This can be easily converted to Lat/Long and I would argue it is probably more up to date than the OS AddressPoint data, given that it is updated by the councils who create the address and updated daily in most cases. However I am not sure if this is available yet, it has been hampered due to licensing restrictions from OS and Royal Mail.

Comment: I would also argue that the NLPG is more accurate than OS Addresspoint.  It's constantly amended and updated by Local Government Authorities across England and Wales, with information from Street Naming & Numbering Officers - the definitive source of addressing information.

You can find out more about the NLPG at http://www.nlpg.org.uk/ and the sales page is at http://www.nlpg.org.uk/nlpg/link.htm?nwid=27 where you can download sample data for development work and get pricing information (I think licensing is a bit more flexible than Addresspoint).

Answer (score 2):

The most accurate way to do this is to use the [Ordnance Survey AddressPoint dataset](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/addresspoint/). Their price list seems to suggest that for use on just one terminal costs around £16,000.

However, if you are willing to sacrifice some accuracy you can do this for free at http://www.nearby.org.uk/coord.cgi using the postcode part of the address. They also have an [API](http://www.nearby.org.uk/api/convert-help.php) which would allow you to automate this. If you have an address without a postcode then you can obtain the postcode from Royal Mail (see http://postcode.royalmail.com/), although I think they only let you lookup a limited number of addresses per day. Also, the Ordnance Survey have released their [CodePoint dataset](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/codepoint/) as part of the [OS OpenData](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendata/) initiative - available to download from https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html. Of course, if you want to represent an address as a point then all the postcode method will provide you with is the location of the centre of the postcode area.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenAddresses.org](http://openaddresses.org/) provides a free (beta) service where users can create/edit/upload addresses.  Unfortunately, the coverage in the UK still appears to be pretty spotty.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that in the UK Post Codes are generally small (25-50 houses) so a post code based system may be acceptably accurate.